# Как можно сохранить текущую позицию скролла при рендере сверху и снизу?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook

Есть блок с динамически подгружаемыми данными по скроллу вверх/вниз, при достижении <300px от края скролла массив данных перерендеривается и скролл улетает вверх, как можно этого избежать и оставить его на той же позиции?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавляйте useEffect который срабатывает при загрузке данных и скролит к вашему элементу:

```
useEffect(()=>{
   document.getElementById("somediv").scrollIntoView();
}, [data])
```

Comment: Да, можно было бы это использовать, если бы не был необходим плавный переход между текущим элементом и тем, который только что отрендерился. Новый элемент должен там уже быть, будто бы и не рендерился, отрендерить его можно в тени, но после этого скролл прыгает в начало.

Comment: С этим решением задача решается конечно, но скажем так достаточно грязно, это не то, что нужно.

Comment: @dataWave делайте тогда cssom минимальную высоту пустого блока и вставляйте в него данные после получения, тут нет другого варианта. Или пример приведите на codesandbox.